# "fxmlLoadException: root value already specified" but I never set a root value

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to open a new window when a hyperlink is clicked. For some reason it worked once and then I could never get it to work again. Every time I run it I get an `javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.` error. The thing is I have not set the root value anywhere.

I tried `loader.setRoot(null)` but that didn't do anything. I never set the root in my fxml or regular method so I'm not sure where it's getting that.

This is the method for loading a new window

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){

        messageSupports.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/MessagingSupportLayout.fxml"));
             //   Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
                loader.setController(new MessagingSupport(mainController));

                mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().add(loader.load());
                secondaryStage.setTitle("Support");
                secondaryStage.setHeight(500);
                secondaryStage.setWidth(350);

                Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());

                secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
                secondaryStage.show();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here's the fxml for `MessagingSupportLayout.fxml`.

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
</BorderPane>
```

The expected results are a new window opens. I set the first window's title, height, width in my main class in a start method. I don't declare a root there or in the fxml for that. I can post it if you need to see it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you calling `loader.load()` twice?

Comment: @Zephyr I don't know and wouldn't you know it, that's what caused the problem.

Comment: @Zephyr if you post it as an answer I can mark you correct and give you points for that.

Comment: No need. Simple issues like this don't really need a full, accepted answer. You could close/delete this question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. the line `mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().add(loader.load());` sets the root. deleting that line solves the problem.